# C - display int as hex using bitwise operators

Tags: c, hex, bit-manipulation

I was reading the SO question about [displaying integers as hex using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878572/convert-integer-to-hex) (without using %x, by using a custom function) and the first answer mentions using bitwise operators to achieve the goal.

But I can't figure it out on my own.  Can anyone tell me how this would be done?

Comment: That answer gives you a "recipe" you can use. Why don't you give it a shot, and if it doesn't work out, post the code you tried so that people can help you fix it?

Comment: The basic loop: `for ( ; n; n /= 16) { prepend(alphabet[n % 16]); }`. No bit fiddling needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope this makes it a little clear to you.

```
char *intToHex(unsigned input)
{
    char *output = malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * 2 + 3);
    strcpy(output, "0x00000000");

    static char HEX_ARRAY[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    //Initialization of 'converted' object

    // represents the end of the string.
    int index = 9;

    while (input > 0 ) 
    {
        output[index--] = HEX_ARRAY[(input & 0xF)];
        //Prepend (HEX_ARRAY[n & 0xF]) char to converted;
        input >>= 4;            
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is *not* an "optimal solution".  Other posters in the same thread suggested a table lookup, which is much, much better.

But, to answer your question, this is pretty much what he was suggesting:

> [Convert integer to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878572/convert-integer-to-hex)
>
> Each 4 bits of an integer maps to exactly one hex digit, if the value
>   of those four bits is less than 10, then its ASCII representation is
>   '0' + value, otherwise it is 'A' + value - 10.
>
> You can extract each group of four digits by shifting and masking. The
>   mask value is 0x0f, and assuming a 32bit integer, the right shift
>   starts at 24 bits and decrements by four for each successive digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int
hex_digit (int ival, int ishift)
{
  ival = (ival >> ishift) & 0xf;
  if (ival < 10)
    ival += '0';
  else
    ival += ('a' + ival - 10);
  return ival;
}

int
main()
{
  int i = 100;
  char s[9];

  s[0] = hex_digit (i, 28);
  s[1] = hex_digit (i, 24);
  s[2] = hex_digit (i, 20);
  s[3] = hex_digit (i, 16);
  s[4] = hex_digit (i, 12);
  s[5] = hex_digit (i, 8);
  s[6] = hex_digit (i, 4);
  s[7] = hex_digit (i, 0);
  s[8] = '\0';

  printf ("hex(%d)=%s\n", i, s);
  return 0;
}
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
gcc -o tmp -g -Wall -pedantic tmp.c
./tmp
hex(100)=00000064
```